# How to set column limit per page in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using *iReport 4.7* and I want to generate report with 40 columns.

How to limit the number of columns per page in *iReport*?

Comment: Are you sure talking about the columns not about the rows?

Answer (score 0):

In the iReport Designer, you can find the Report Inspector,right click on your file and choose Page Format,there you can give the desired size and page setup under Custom Format.

Later you can work on the updated page size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to properties tab and find "Columns" then Change number to 40 in "Columns".

[>>Click here<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E33Aj.png)